# css focus property not working properly

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS transform and transition properties. When I hover the image, the button shows up as expected over the image. The problem I found now is that when I focus on the image by pressing the TAB key, the image simply disappears and only the button shows.

Html:

```
<div class="main">
  <img src="phone.jpg" >
  <div class="paragraph">This wil be centered</div>
  <div class="content">
     <button>Nokia 7210 Classic</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix{
  clear: both;
}section
{
  text-align: center;
}
.main{
  float:left;
  width:30%;
  text-align: center;
  border:10px solid white;
  width:306px;
  height:306px;
  margin : 50px auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.paragraph{
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-300%);
 border: 5px solid grey;
 background-color: grey;
 opacity: 0.5;
}
.main:hover .content,
.main:focus .content{
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-340px);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 700ms;
}
.content{
  width: 306px;
  height: 306px;
  background: rgba(51, 102, 255, 0.5);    
}
img{
  height:inherit;
  width:inherit;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 5000ms;
}
button{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: black;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font: 16px tahoma;  
}
button:hover{
 opacity: 0.5;
}
```

How can I overcome this problem in a way that the same effect happens on FOCUS?

Comment: `.main` is a div that cannot receive focus. That selector never retrieves anything. The *button* has focus, but CSS doesn't currently allow you to select parent elements based on its children.

Comment: Can you create an example? Looks ok to me http://output.jsbin.com/vokozurego/

Comment: @Sotiris.From the link you sent,note that when you hover,it behaves perfectly. But you press the tab key, it goes funny.

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Tabbing wants to access the button which is tabbable, but it's out of view so it needs to bring it into view, so it scrolls down the hypothetical box which isn't normally scrollable in order to do that. There's no way to fix that outside of "don't put tabbable content outside of the normal view if you don't want to break things." Or give the button a negative/invalid tabindex so it can't be reached with the tab key (bad for users who rely on the keyboard).

Comment: @animuson. It makes sense. Will try another way around. cause the idea of using focus was thinking more of the mobile devices...because the dont use clicks,but focus

Comment: @WosleyAlarico Which browser are you using to test? Your code works fine for me in Chrome

Comment: @PatoSalazar.Then its weird cause am using chrome too!